# grep - RegEx multiple-criteria select

Tags: regex, linux, grep, gnu, pcre

Given a file containing this string:

```
IT1*1*EA*VN*ABC@SAC*X*500@REF*ZZ*OK@IT1*1*CS*VN*ABC@SAC*X*500@REF*ZZ*BAR@IT1*1*EA*VN*ABC@SAC*X*500@REF*ZZ*BAR@IT1*1*EA*VN*ABC@SAC*X*500@REF*ZZ*OK@
```

The goal is to extract the following:

```
IT1*1*EA*VN*ABC@SAC*X*500@REF*ZZ*BAR@
```

With the criteria being:

1. The IT1 "line" must contain `*EA*`
2. The REF line must contain `BAR`

Some notes for consideration:

- "@" can be thought of as a line break
- A "group" of lines contains lines starting with IT1 and ending with REF
- I am running GNU grep 3.7.

The goal is to select the "group" of lines meeting the criteria.

I tried the following:

```
grep -oP "IT1[^@]*EA[^@]*@.*REF[^@]*BAR[^@]*@" file.txt
```

But it captures characters from the beginning of the example.

Also tried to use lookarounds:

```
grep -oP "(?<=IT1[^@]*EA[^@]*@).*?(?=REF[^@]*BAR[^@]*@)" file.txt
```

But my version of grep returns:

> grep: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is that `.*` will match characters from the first `IT1` with `EA` to the last `REF` with `BAR`. You need to ensure the match doesn't go past the next `IT1`, which you can do by replacing `.*` with a [tempered greedy token](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) `(?:(?!@IT1).)*`:

```
IT1[^@]*EA[^@]*@(?:(?!@IT1).)*REF[^@]*BAR[^@]*@
```

This will only match from an `IT1` to its corresponding `REF`.

Regex demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/7M2e55/1)

Comment: Very good use of tempered greedy pattern ++

Answer (score 2):

You don't need PCREs for this, a simple POSIX ERE will do:

```
$ grep -oE 'IT1[^@]*EA*[^@]*@[^@]*@REF[^@]*BA[^@]*@' file
IT1*1*EA*VN*ABC@SAC*X*500@REF*ZZ*BAR@
```

If I had to operate on that data, though, I wouldn't use grep on it like that as the regexp becomes lengthy and grep would read the whole input file into memory at once so YMMV with large input files.

Instead I'd use awk to treat it as 3-line records of `@`-separated fields and then you can trivially do whatever you like with the fields and/or whole records, e.g. using GNU awk for multi-char `RS` and `RT`:

```
$ awk -v RS='([^@]*@){3}' -F'@' '{$0=RT} ($1 ~ /EA/) && ($3 ~ /BAR/)' file
IT1*1*EA*VN*ABC@SAC*X*500@REF*ZZ*BAR@
```

The above only reads 3 `@`-separated strings at a time into memory and breaks down the input into these records and fields:

```
$ awk -v RS='([^@]*@){3}' -F'@' 'RT{$0=RT; print; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print "\t" i, $i}' file
IT1*1*EA*VN*ABC@SAC*X*500@REF*ZZ*OK@
        1 IT1*1*EA*VN*ABC
        2 SAC*X*500
        3 REF*ZZ*OK
        4
IT1*1*CS*VN*ABC@SAC*X*500@REF*ZZ*BAR@
        1 IT1*1*CS*VN*ABC
        2 SAC*X*500
        3 REF*ZZ*BAR
        4
IT1*1*EA*VN*ABC@SAC*X*500@REF*ZZ*BAR@
        1 IT1*1*EA*VN*ABC
        2 SAC*X*500
        3 REF*ZZ*BAR
        4
IT1*1*EA*VN*ABC@SAC*X*500@REF*ZZ*OK@
        1 IT1*1*EA*VN*ABC
        2 SAC*X*500
        3 REF*ZZ*OK
        4
```

There's an empty field at the end of each record due to the `@` at the end of each record. That can be trivially handled however you like (removed, ignored, kept, whatever).

If you don't have GNU awk you can do the same using any awk with just slightly more code:

```
$ awk -v RS='@' -F'@' '{$0=prev $0 RS; prev=(NR%3 ? $0 : "")} !prev && ($1 ~ /EA/) && ($3 ~ /BAR/)' file
IT1*1*EA*VN*ABC@SAC*X*500@REF*ZZ*BAR@
```

```
$ awk -v RS='@' -F'@' '{$0=prev $0 RS; prev=(NR%3 ? $0 : "")} !prev{print; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print "\t" i, $i}' file
IT1*1*EA*VN*ABC@SAC*X*500@REF*ZZ*OK@
        1 IT1*1*EA*VN*ABC
        2 SAC*X*500
        3 REF*ZZ*OK
        4
IT1*1*CS*VN*ABC@SAC*X*500@REF*ZZ*BAR@
        1 IT1*1*CS*VN*ABC
        2 SAC*X*500
        3 REF*ZZ*BAR
        4
IT1*1*EA*VN*ABC@SAC*X*500@REF*ZZ*BAR@
        1 IT1*1*EA*VN*ABC
        2 SAC*X*500
        3 REF*ZZ*BAR
        4
IT1*1*EA*VN*ABC@SAC*X*500@REF*ZZ*OK@
        1 IT1*1*EA*VN*ABC
        2 SAC*X*500
        3 REF*ZZ*OK
        4
```